# How to connect c# winform aplication with Interactive Brokers

Tags: c#, winforms, interactive-brokers

I need to connect clients (c#, winforms) appliction with Interactive Brokers and improve app with some "stock market" functionality.
First I start project with reading IB documents and learning IB's API. 
After I did that I'm just more confused and didn't find anything useful!
I want to ask if someone knows where I can find documentation that would explain everything from the beginning, from creating test accounts, using IB's API, to connect to IB system...
If such documents doesn't exist can anyone give me answer the following questions:

- Does my application using IB's API can directly connect to IB system or it must use TWS (Trader Workstation)?
- What is the purpose of IB's API when TWS must be running in the background?
- Is it possible to create a test account on IB?

I would be grateful for any advice, a link to the documents or examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried too, and gave up.

Comment: Download TWS API from their web site. It comes with sample code. In order to connect, you must have either Trader Workstation or IB Gateway running. They have a demo account you can use to test your code but it is somewhat limited. For a realistic test you need to open a brokerage account with them and then set up your own paper trading account.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to use IB API. You can connect either to TWS application or to Gateway application (same as TWS but without user interface). Gateway is specifically designed for API use so you do not have to run full TWS on the background.

Interactive brokers does support paper trading account. It is just like your real account with full functionality but fake money so you can test your API or system.

Here is very simple example of how to send an order through API:
http://www.bowgett.com/Blog/post/how-to-send-an-order-to-ib-tws-in-just-68-lines

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, your C#/C++/Python/Java/VB/etc. program incorporates the IB API code libraries.  This program then connects to either the IB Gateway or Trader Workstation (TWS).  So yes you need to keep ether the IB Gateway or TWS running and connected to the IB data center all of the time your program is running.

You can create a paper trading account with IB to do testing. You can also use the "edemo" account to test basic API functionality and connectivity. However the edemo account only sends back some canned data to most market data requests. You can do a lot with edemo as far as testing goes but to see anything "real" you would need to open a paper trading account (and eventually a funded account).

In addition to the tips others suggested, you might find some introductory tutorials useful. For example: http://holowczak.com/ib-api-tutorials-by-programming-language/  has tutorials on IB API using a variety of different languages and Windows / Console alternatives.  In these tutorials, the interaction between your program, TWS/IB Gateway and the data center are discussed. Also discussed are the API architecture and the publish/subscribe messaging model that IB (and many other market data APIs) uses.

Comment: This would be better suited to a comment rather than an answer. Answers that solely link to other resources and don't show any code samples are generally frowned upon by the Stack Overflow community.